# Why you cannot have Tab in sed -i "1i \t 'word'" file?

Tags: sed

Pseudocode

```
printf "Masi \nwas \nhere" > /tmp/2
sed -i "1i \tword \t 'include word'" /tmp/2
```

Expected output: tab before the first `word`. Output: `tword   'include word'`. 
Trying to use variable to solve the too-few-ticks-problem

```
printf "masi \nwas \nhere" > /tmp/2
sentence="\tword \t 'include word'"
sed -i "1i $sentence" /tmp/2
```

Output: same problem `tword    'include word'`.

Comment: The first \ is interpreted as the delimiter for the `i` command

Comment: @steeldriver How can you prevent it?

Comment: `sed -i "1i\\$sentence" /tmp/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i '1i\\t'$sentence /tmp/2
```

or

```
sed -i "1i\\\t$sentence" /tmp/2
```

The text to insert starts after the first `\`. Single-quote the `sed` script to stop your shell from doing thing with the `\t` (or insert yet another `\` as in the second example above). With single quotes, concatenate `$sentence` with the `sed` script so that it gets expanded by the shell.

Answer (score 2):

While `sed` may be able to interpret `\t` in a regular expression, none of your script uses it that way.  Rather, it is using `\t` as a literal string.

You could do what you want like this:

```
printf "Masi \nwas \nhere" > /tmp/2
sed -i "1i XwordXinclude word'" /tmp/2
sed -i '1,1s/X/\t/g' /tmp/2
```

Comment: A *substitute* command would use it as part of a regular expression.  An *insert* command does not.